# Creating a tgz file through PHP exec()

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a .tgz file through the PHP exec(); function in an AJAX web interface, however, my code isn't making any files, and it isn't writing out any errors.

This code works in shell:

```
tar cvfz destination/testfolder.tgz source/testfolder
```

I'm setting the `destination/testfolder.tgz` and the `source/testfolder` as variables in PHP since they change based on user input, so my code looks something like this:

```
$q=$_GET["q"];
$part = explode("/", $q);
$source = $q;
$dest = "destination/" .$part[1].".tgz";
exec("tar cvfz " . $dest . " " . $source);
```

I've echoed the `"tar cvfz " . $dest . " " . $source` and copy/pasted it into shell, which works, so I'm confused as to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Just as an observation, you need to be very careful putting a `_GET` variable directly into the shell. I could easily pass `; rm -rf /` into the GET variables, and then entire server would be erased.

Comment: Like Dagon said, it may be permissions. _Temporarily_ do `chmod -R 777 /path/to/the/directory` to see if it's the problem. Then, gradually back off the permissions for security reasons.

Comment: I didn't even think about doing something like that, but I'm just using this a personal file server and listing the folders through a form, not with any sort of text field input. The chmod worked (thank you both!), but what permission would you recommend setting the folder to that isn't 777? I don't mind leaving it as 777 since it will be behind a password, but it just might be better to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, for the same security issue @David mentioned, the PHP exec() function has very limited permissions - it can't even create files. Instead of chmodding the file to 777, which is very dangerous even temporarily, I suggest you create a temporary folder either in a sandbox or at any non-harmful location then ch **own** it to the user/group of the PHP interpreter's user/group with somewhat restrictive permissions (e. g. chmod 700 for the directory, 600 for the files inside).

Comment: This & the other comments are going to work for me, I'm probably just going to leave them to the default folders (since this is for personal use), but thank you!